# Crypto Liberary for Iphone, BlackBerry, Android and .Net

Tags: .net, iphone, encryption, blackberry, cryptography

We are working on a application suite with support of windows(.net), Iphone, Android and Blackberry and all these application shares the same data (syncs with a wcf services).

Whenever a device ads a new record, it encrypts the data and and saves in the local database and on sync it post the record to server as it is.

Now when the same record opens on the other device it need to be decrypted first and here comes the problem the cryptography library we used doesn't support iPhone. its name is Bouncy Castle. (www.bouncycastle.org)

Now, we are looking for the replacement of BouncyCastle for Iphone OR if there is some sort of tested library that support all above plateforms then please let us know. Please note that we are looking for AES256 encryption algo.

Thanks in Advance
Mubashar

Answer (score 2):

BlackBerry has native support for AES in their API:

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/AESEncryptorEngine.html

Answer (score 0):

You can compile and link against OpenSSL on iPhone without any problems.

Comment: It's a C library, so if you're able to compile, link against and call C code from your applications it should work. But if you're unable to call C code, or unable to link against C library for any reason, then it probably won't work.

Comment: You are not able to compile or link against C code on Blackberry.

Comment: In this case, you could use OpenSSL for a replacement of BouncyCastle on iPhone, and just use Bouncy Castle for everything else. It's not like you're going to be able to share the codebase between iPhone and Blackberry anyway...